# what is alternative way to FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python-3.x

```
file_data = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile (join(path, f))]
    for line in file_data:
        if ( line[-1:] == '\n' ):
            line = line[:-1]
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] System cannot find a way to development

Comment: What has that got to do with machine-learning?

Comment: wrong tag . I fixed it.

Comment: Just use a `try/except`.

Comment: `line = line[:-1]` has no effect unless you're using `line` after that. You'll need to iterate `for n in range(len(file_data))` if your intention is to change elements (lines) in the `file_data` array.